# How to remove an item from a sorted doubly linked list?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a sorted doubly linked list that always starts with the first element as `null` and ends with the last element as null. When the list is empty it look like this: `{null, null}`. When I insert the values `​​a, b, c`, the list looks like this: `{null, a, b, c, null}`.

I have a `removeFirst()` method that should remove the first item from the list and the list should look like this: `{null, b, c, null}`. And the removed item is returned.

I also have a `removeLast()` method that removes the last element so the list should look like this: `{null, b, null}`. And the removed item is returned.

The `removeElement()` method should remove an item from the list in any place and returns true. If the item is not in the list, it returns false.

The problem with the code I have now is that `removeFirst()` removes the first item from the list which is `null`. And I have the same problem with the `removeLast()` method, it also removes the last element in the list which is null. But the first and last elements in the list should always be null and should not be removed.

`removeElement()` method do not remove any items from the list. I can not see what I'm missing.

Here is my code so far:

```
// removes the first item in the list and returns the string
public String removeFirst() {

    // if the list is empty
    if (this.size == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    Node tempNode = first;

    // if there is only one item in the list
    if (first.next == null) {
        last = null;
    } else {
        first.next.previous = null;
        first = first.next;
    }

    size--;

    return tempNode.data;
}

// removes the last item in the list and returns the string
public String removeLast() {

    // if the list is empty
    if (this.size == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    Node tempNode = last.previous;

    // if there is only one item in the list
    if (first.equals(last)) {
        first.previous = null;
        first.next = last;
        last.previous = first;
        last.next = null;

        tempNode.next = null;

    } else {
        last.previous.next = null;
        last = last.previous;
        tempNode.previous = null;
    }

    size--;

    return tempNode.data;
}

// removes an item from the list
public boolean removeElement(String element) {
    boolean removed = false;

    try {
        // if the first element in the list should be removed
        if (first.data.equals(element)) {
            // if there is only one item in the list
            if (first.equals(last)) {
                last = null;
                first = first.next;

            } else {
                first.next.previous = null;
                first = first.next;
            }

            size--;
            removed = true;

            // if the last item in the list should be deleted
        } else if (last.data.equals(element)) {
            last.previous.next = null;
            last = last.previous;

            size--;
            removed = true;

        } else {
            Node before = first;
            Node after = first.next;

            // as long as there are more elements in the list
            while (first.next != null) {
                if (after.data.compareTo(element) == 0) {

                    before.next = after.next;
                    after.next.previous = before.next;

                    size--;
                    removed = true;

                    break;
                }

                before = after;
                after = after.next;
            }

        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        removed = false;
    }

    return removed;
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions, but two I wanna ask. First of all: _is there a reason why there is a 'try-catch' block for a NullPointerException?_ Second: _have you debugged your code already?_

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ "SO is a terrible debugger."

Comment: because if i want to remove an element from the list which does not exist in the list I get a NullPointerException

Comment: @n247s if I could solve the problem then I would not had asked the question

Comment: RemoveElement() should call removeFirst() and removeLast() in that if-statement and avoid code duplication. In removeFirst() you test differently whether the list is empty than in removeLast(). in removeElement() you do a .equals() and later you do a .compareTo().

Comment: @onnoweb the removeElement() should only return true or false and the two other methods returns a String

Comment: That's because I was trying to fix the problem, then I ended up with this code

Comment: I think also there is a terminology problem. When you say the first and last elements of the list are always null then I assume you mean that element's "String data" is null? And so the methods removeFirst() and removeLast() are really removeFirstNonNull() and removeLastNonNull().